# sqrtf function without including math.h library

Tags: c

I am trying to find length of hypotenuse of a triangle when given base and hight.

i followed recommended method of adding math.h library and get square root by using sqrtf. but i am trying my own logic to get result

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c;

    printf("enter a,b");
    scanf("%d%d",&a , &b);
    c*c = a*a+b*b;

    printf("%d",c);
    return 0;
}
```

i am expecing to value of c but i am getting compilation error.

Comment: C is not an equation solver language. `c*c` will do multiplication and give a numeric result, and that's all. This result is not a variable you can assign to (lvalue), it is just a value (rvalue) you can immediately use.

Comment: hint: Newton-Raphson

Comment: r.c: In function ‘main’:
r.c:7:6: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
  c*c = a*a+b*b;
      ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, an assignment expression does not assert that the left operand has the same value as the right operand and leave the computer or software to figure out how to make that true.  An assignment expression instructs the computer to store the value of the right operand in the object that is the left operand. So the left operand must designate an object.

To calculate the square root of a value without using library functions, you must write your own code to do the calculations.

Comment: Surprisingly this too was an exact duplicate.